# Unit Testing Timed Removal of Dictionary Value

Tags: c#, unit-testing, caching, dictionary, timer

I am writing an in-memory cache (for lack of a better term) in C#. Writing the cache was the easy part, but testing it is another...

All of my research into testing classes that use timers is to mock the timer and inject it into the class. With this, a new timer needs to be initialized for each order that is added to the cache. Passing a timer into the Add function would solve this, but classes consuming the OrderCache shouldn't be responsible for passing a timer to it.

I need to verify that

- the timer has been initialized
- Remove is called for the proper order after the specified duration
- the order is updated in the Dictionary and no timer is created when adding the same order twice

  ```
  private readonly Dictionary<int, Order> _orders;

  private TimeSpan _cacheDuration;

  public OrderCache(TimeSpan cacheDuration)
  {
      _cacheDuration = cacheDuration;
      _orders = new Dictionary<int, Order>();
  }

  public void Add(Order order)
  {
      var cachedOrder = GetOrderById(order.Id);
      if (cachedOrder == null)
      {
          _orders.Add(order.Id, order);
          var timer = new Timer(_cacheDuration.TotalMilliseconds);
          timer.Elapsed += (sender, args) => Remove(order.Id);
      }
      else
      {
          _orders[order.Id] = order;
      }
  }

  public Order GetOrderById(int orderId)
  {
      return _orders.ContainsKey(orderId) ? _orders[orderId] : null;
  }

  public void Remove(int orderId)
  {
      if (_orders.ContainsKey(orderId))
      {
          _orders.Remove(orderId);
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Do you actually need a timer to *actively* remove entries, or can you passively remove them based on a clock giving the current time? Also note that `Dictionary<,>` isn't thread-safe...

Comment: This is being used in a Windows service. The consuming class is a poller that uses a Timer to invoke the polling method. It's currently housing it's own Dictionary to prevent it from invoking the order received event multiple times for the same order. The problem is that this Dictionary is never cleared out and since this is a service, it could eventually cause a memory overflow.

Comment: So why not make the polling method just see if there's anything that needs to be cleared? If that's being called regularly, I don't think you need to schedule timers all over the place. (Or perhaps schedule *one* timer to clear things down, if you want.) The point about Dictionary not being thread-safe is still *highly* relevant though... you need to think about that carefully. (If you're using .NET 4 or higher, consider ConcurrentDictionary.)

Comment: Sort of off on a tangent, but are the various timers getting cleaned up?  I can see them being created and elapsing but nothing else.  The default for AutoReset is true, so it looks like they will continue triggering every interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A: the timer has been initialized

Q: You should avoid White-Box Testing, because if internal implementation changed, but not behavior, interface or contract, you should rewrite test again.

A: Remove is called for the proper order after the specified duration

Q: You can write test:

```
[Test]
void Should_remove_...()
{
    MockTimer timer = new MockTimer();    

    MyCache cache = new MyCache(timer);
    DateTime expiredAt = DateTime.Now.Add(..);
    cache.Add("key", "value", expiredAt);

    timer.SetTime(expiredAt);

    Assert.That(cache, Is.Empty)
}
```

PS: I recommend the use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.aspx

Answer (score 1):

[With that being said :)](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TwoHardThings.html):

> There are only two hard things in Computer Science: cache invalidation and naming things.
>
> -- Phil Karlton

@JonSkeet's advise is the way to go - either cleanup the cache on each poll (if happens often), or have a thread to cleanup regularly.

If you still think to preserve your approach, instead of passing in a timer into the cache, pass `ITimerFactory`. Then each `Add` call can use the factory to create a timer, and set it accordingly.

You can mock the factory to produce mock timer and set it to the proper time. which you can control for your tests.

Your test will have the form (pseudo):

```
var timer = new Mock<ITimer>();
var factory = new Mock<ITimerFactory>();
factory.Setup(f => f.CreateTimer()).Returns(timer.Object);
....
....
timer.Verify(t => t.SetTime(expiredAt), Times.Once());
```